# Unable to create the Web site 'http://www.example.com'. Found

Tags: iis-7.5

Whenever I try to `File/New Website` using a Web Location of HTTP in *Visual Web Developer Express 2008* or *2010*. I get the error:

> Unable to create the Web site 'http://www.example.com'. Found

I have tried *MS Visual Express Developer 2008* and *2010* and get the same results. I have tried three different machines and get the same error. I have installed *Front Page Server* extensions for *IIS 7.5* and get the same error.

It appears this may be some kind of setup issue but I cannot find it.

Does anyone have any idea regarding what I am missing?